# Sourcecode syntax highlighting with Code Folding

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, folding

I know there are many syntax highlighting scripts in Javascript for adding syntax highlighting to source code, I am looking to see if such a thing exist with the addition of having Code Folding like many IDE's have.

Do you know if anything exist like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors#List_of_features), I found `CodeMirror`, which is not only a syntax highlighter, but also a code editor. However, according to the [following code folding demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/folding.html), you can use it just as a viewer.

It's written in Javascript and it supports a lot of languages ([full list here](http://codemirror.net/)).